# Android Studio Logcat Filter exact tag

Tags: android-studio, filter, logcat, android-logcat

Is it possible to filter an exact tag in Android Studio Logcat? I'm looking for the tag "lights" but every tag containing "lights" like "lightService" is also printed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In logcat on righthand-side in "Edit Filter Configuration" new filter can be created. The tag field is processed as regex. So if I enter "lights" everything containing "lights" like "lightService" is found. The correct regex is "^lights$" to only find "lights".